# GRUB command prompt instead of normal boot for Windows 10 after deleting Ubuntu partition

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

My PC is an Inspiron 5547 with dual boot system with Windows 10 version 1709 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Now due to some issue with my HD, I deleted the Linux partition, but its showing me a GRUB error during the boot. When the `exit` command is executed it moves to the boot option where a selection of OS need to be done i.e. Linux or Windows.

Have tried using recovery drive of Windows to fix the MBR, but it shows nothing to repair "ALL IS WELL". I have used `ls` at the `grub>` (not `grub rescue>`)command prompt but nothing turns up i.e. `Unknown file system`

[image]

All I can think of is to install Linux in a USB drive and just use it without installation to update GRUB. All I want to do is remove grub so that whenever the system boots it starts with default OS.

Comment: If your Windows is original (factory installed) then it's in UEFI mode therefore the old methods you said you followed couldn't possibly work.

Comment: You haven't make it clear what exactly you want, e.g., to simply start up windows 10, or just the annoying grub thing to disappear. The latter being the case, you can boot into windows 10 and clear the grub resude on your ESP via the 'bcdedit' commandline or the "easyuefi" software.

Comment: @funicorn want to disappear that grub.

Comment: @MichaelBay yes it is Windows original (factory installed)

Comment: @ankur There should be an entry in the UEFI settings allowing to set the default os loader. Enter BIOS and change that to sth. like "windows boot manager..." then reboot. At this stage the computer boots directly to Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Using the LiveCD, start gparted and temporarily remove the ESP flag from the EFI partition so you can mount it. Mount the EFI partition and delete the folder /EFI/Ubuntu. Use gparted to reset the ESP flag, and reboot. The EFI firmware should recognize the change and set Windows to boot.

Comment: frankly speaking I didn't understood what you said but I tried to reinstall windows 10 but the result was same. Can you please elaborate more or share a link of video or step by step guide that might be available?